# How to make android boot straight into an app without showing the UI

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-developer-api, app-startup

we're developing an app that runs on android tablets. The app is an DeviceOwner/Admin app (the device can be set up as COSU device if it helps) and runs in LockTaskMode (the full kiosk mode). We want to launch into the app straight after boot ideally without ever showing the android UI (we don't mind if the boot takes longer). Also we want to have an option (for admins) to exit the kiosk and get back to the normal android UI with all it's features.

We tried 2 solutions:

- Implementation via the `BroadcastReceiver`s `onReceive()` and `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. This works but launches the app after ~15 seconds, and the user is free to do whatever during that time which is not optimal.
- Setting the application as the default home screen (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54922966/22957205)) which starts the application immediately after boot, but makes it impossible to exit the application and return to the normal android UI. I tried clearing the default action on the button press via `mDevicePolicyManager.clearPackagePersistentPreferredActivities( mAdminComponentName,"com.example.xpms_workstation")` but it doesn't seem to work

We're developing on Flutter but this part is only for android devices

Comment: This question you linked is in fact a duplicate since it addresses exactly what you're trying to do: [How to directly boot your android app straight from splash screen, without showing the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915004/how-to-directly-boot-your-android-app-straight-from-splash-screen-without-showi)

Comment: For getting around not being able to exit the application - The "normal android UI" you are talking about is just another launcher application, which you can launch from an intent with the package name (this will depend on what device you are using)